# How do I load a module to PulseAudio server?

Tags: linux-mint, pulseaudio

I recently followed this [guide to simultaneous audio outputs](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1240).

It works great but now I have a huge name for the virtual device in the audio control panel making it expand off my screen. In Pulse Audio Control Panel (pavucontrol), I tried right clicking and using "Rename Device..." but an error pops up saying the following:

[image: Error I get in pavucontrol when renaming a device.]

My next logical question is how do I load `module-device-manager` in the PulseAudio server? I tried googling it but nothing I found was relevant.

A little bit of help please? I don't care what it gets renamed to, I just want the control panel to fit on my screen.

The current name is "Simultaneous output to GF100 High Definition Audi Controller Digital Stereo, EMU20k2 [X-Fi Titanium Series] Analog Stereo, GF108 High Definition Audio Controller Digital Stereo (HDMI), Built-in Audio Stereo"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To load a specific module to the PA server, you add it to `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:

```
load-module module-device-manager
```

Changes can also be made during runtime using `pacmd`.

Comment: Added `load-module module-device-manager` to the end of `/etc/pulse/default.pa`, restarted, and now it let's me rename devices. Thanks!

Comment: Note that pulseaudio can also run with --system, in which case you need to add it to /etc/pulse/system.pa instead of default.pa (this is usually when you run it as root).